# Перегрузка бинарного оператора "-"

Tags: c++

Почему же не работает?
Ошибка  C2676   бинарный "-": "coord" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class coord
{
private :
    T value;
public:
    coord(T out_value = 0)
    {
        value = out_value;
    }

    auto operator-(const coord& outsider) -> decltype (this->value - outsider.value)
    {
        return (this->value - outsider.value);
    }



};

int main()
{
    coord<double> first(10);
    coord<int> second(3.3);
    std::cout << (first - second);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так у вас же `first` и `second` разных типов

Comment: В этом и суть. Что бы разные типы обрабатывались.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как у вас `first` и `second` имеют разные типы (шаблоны инстанцируются с разными типами), то вы не можете использовать бинарный оператор, определенный только для конкретного типа. Для того, чтобы оно работало со всеми инстансами нужно чтобы этот оператор также был шаблонным. Для этого придется сделать `value` публичным членом, так как нужен будет доступ снаружи объекта:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class coord {
public:
  T value;

public:
  coord(T out_value = 0) { value = out_value; }
};

template <typename FirstValueType, typename SecondValueType>
auto operator-(const coord<FirstValueType> &first,
               const coord<SecondValueType> &second)
    -> decltype(first.value - second.value) {
  return (first.value - second.value);
}

int main() {
  coord<double> first(10.);
  coord<int> second(3.3);
  std::cout << (first - second);
  return 0;
}
```

В примере я сделал функцию свободной, но можно реализовать и внутри класса. Для этого нужно будет оставить только `SecondValueType` в шаблонных аргументах.

Comment: а вот здесь   `coord<double> first(10.);
  coord<int> second(3.3);` даже не ругнулся компилятор?

Comment: @KoVadim сдесь варнинг, но это уже на совести ТС